# Mongo Db unable to insert large array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongo-java-driver

i have problems inserting an array of string to mongo db. After a specific size of the array the driver hangs - no exception (timeout or error) is thrown. When i reduce the length everything works fine. Can somebody explain this strange behaviour? Sorry for this newbee question but i couldn't find an existing question for this.

*Mongo DB Version*

> MongoDB server version: 3.4.3

*Java Driver:*

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**Working Document**

```
{
  "epc": [
                "urn:epc:id:sscc:1234567.4000002750",
                "urn:epc:id:sscc:1234567.4000002751"
            ]
}
```

**Not Working Document**

```
    {
  "epc": [
                "urn:epc:id:sscc:1234567.4000002750",
                "urn:epc:id:sscc:1234567.4000002751",
                "urn:epc:id:sscc:1234567.4000002752",
                "urn:epc:id:sscc:1234567.4000002753",
                "urn:epc:id:sscc:1234567.4000002751",
                "urn:epc:id:sscc:1234567.4000002752",
                "urn:epc:id:sscc:1234567.4000002753",
                "urn:epc:id:sscc:1234567.4000002751",
                "urn:epc:id:sscc:1234567.4000002752",
                "urn:epc:id:sscc:1234567.4000002753",
                "urn:epc:id:sscc:1234567.4000002751",
                "urn:epc:id:sscc:1234567.4000002751",
                "urn:epc:id:sscc:1234567.4000002752",
                "urn:epc:id:sscc:1234567.4000002753",
                "urn:epc:id:sscc:1234567.4000002753",
                "urn:epc:id:sscc:1234567.4000002751",
                "urn:epc:id:sscc:1234567.4000002751",
                "urn:epc:id:sscc:1234567.4000002752",
                "urn:epc:id:sscc:1234567.4000002753",
                "urn:epc:id:sscc:1234567.4000002751",
                "urn:epc:id:sscc:1234567.4000002752",
                "urn:epc:id:sscc:1234567.4000002753",
                "urn:epc:id:sscc:1234567.4000002751",
                "urn:epc:id:sscc:1234567.4000002752",
                "urn:epc:id:sscc:1234567.4000002753",
                "urn:epc:id:sscc:1234567.4000002751",
                "urn:epc:id:sscc:1234567.4000002752",
                "urn:epc:id:sscc:1234567.4000002753",
                "urn:epc:id:sscc:1234567.4000002751",
                "urn:epc:id:sscc:1234567.4000002752",
                "urn:epc:id:sscc:1234567.4000002753",
                "urn:epc:id:sscc:1234567.4000002751",
                "urn:epc:id:sscc:1234567.4000002752",
                "urn:epc:id:sscc:1234567.4000002753",
                "urn:epc:id:sscc:1234567.4000002751",
                "urn:epc:id:sscc:1234567.4000002752"
              ]
}
```

Comment: What is between your client and the mongodb server? are you using some special setting on the client side?  your example looks quite right in size, usually the maximum bson object size is about 16777216 bytes.

Comment: Openstack environment, i started the latest docker image

Comment: just curious,  can you run the same update command from the shell? doing mongo your_server and db.collecltion.updateOne(.....)

Comment: wft...i downloaded mongo version 3.4 and installed it locally - everything works. I will try it with another docker version

Comment: It's a problem with open stack... same docker image works locally also

Answer (score 0):

It's a firewall problem. Now i'm tunneling the connections to the remote vm via SSH.

[image]

```
 MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost");
```